# OutOfMemoryError when joining a list of Strings in Java

Tags: java, out-of-memory

So. I've tried:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(String bufferItem: buffer){
    sb.append(bufferItem);
}
```

and I've also tried:

```
String.join("\n", buffer)
```

I am joining a large files(under 10GB) in memory on a system with more than 100GB. The following is the stack trace. How can I solve this problem?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.hugeCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:161)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.newCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:155)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.ensureCapacityInternal(AbstractStringBuilder.java:125)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:448)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:136)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:76)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:484)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:166)
    at java.util.StringJoiner.add(StringJoiner.java:185)
    at java.lang.String.join(String.java:2504)
```

Comment: A 9GB file sounds rather large to me actually.  How much memory is being allocated to the Java heap?  You should check your JVM memory settings.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good idea in general. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Can you increase the max heap size in the JVM and try again?  There's a good chance you'll need to break this process into chunks in order to remain within the allotted memory during execution.  You might check out Hadoop MapReduce for this sort of memory-intensive job.

Comment: `I am joining a large files` - then maybe you should actually be writing to a file instead of trying to do this In memory.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You cannot create strings with that many characters. The `OutOfMemoryError` is not because the heap was full, but because you're trying to build a String larger than the maximum possible size.

The maximum possible size is defined as 2 to the power 31, minus 1, minus 8. That's roughly 2Gb if you only use single-byte characters in a file. See the source of `AbstractStringBuilder`.

```
/**
 * The maximum size of array to allocate (unless necessary).
 * Some VMs reserve some header words in an array.
 * Attempts to allocate larger arrays may result in
 * OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
 */
private static final int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = Integer.MAX_VALUE - 8;
```

You simply cannot create strings larger than that.

Why do you want to join the files in memory when you can join them while streaming them to disk?

Comment: I had a hunch about this. I need to send these files to a HTTP service. So storing them on the disk just seemed unnecessary to me. Especially since the amount of memory I have on the box where I am running my Java job is significantly larger than the files that I need to write to the service.

Comment: I am using Httpcon.getOutputStream() to write my data to. So I am now trying writing one string at a time to the stream and flushing it. Let me see if that works.

Comment: You can also stream directly to an `OutputStream` or `Writer` that is attached to the HTTP service request (depends on the library you're using - `URLConnection.getOutputStream()` for example. But I doubt that there are many web services that take files that large, or it would need to have been very carefully written, because often the whole request is first read into memory on the webservice side, and there it will run into the same or a similar problem as you just have.

Comment: The service on the other side is written in Python and it can handle large file sizes. We have done something like that before.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Requested array size exceeds VM limit
        at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
        at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)

Comment: That's actually the same error for the same reason. What library are you using to make HTTP service requests? You need to find one (or you need to configure it) to not buffer the request. You could try setting the Content-length header yourself to the number of bytes in advance (before writing to the outputstream); determining the Content-length header that needs to go before the output may be one reason why the library is buffering.

Comment: So, I am using HttpsURLConnection. I am indeed setting the header: httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(length * 2));

I loop through my list and add up the string lengths and store it in length variable.

Comment: Alright - I haven't used HttpUrlConnection for a while, but it has a method that you need to call to set the content length. If you don't set it, it will buffer first. You need to call the method `setFixedLengthStreamingMode(long)` to tell it how many bytes you're going to stream. Why are you doing `length * 2`; what is `length` here?

Comment: I was kind of too lazy to check the encoding of my string lol. I just made a guess that it is UTF-16. Length is the number of characters in total. That seemed to have worked for other smaller files.

Comment: If your service supports chunked encoding, then it's a good idea to use that. In that case I don't think you need to set the length in advance. But it's something that needs to be supported by the receives of the call. I guess it depends on the python web framework that you're using although I'm not that familiar with web service programming in python.

Comment: Okay! So, setFixedLengthStreamingMode worked. I got rid of the * 2; I need to little bit more about character encoding and all, instead of randomly guessing what to fill in for content-length and the parameter to pass to this function call.

Comment: However, it is taking a really long time, writing this way. I tried with a 15MB file and even that took more than 2 minutes.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt even data which needs to be processed can be Streamed without creating one big String of all the data eg SAX parser for XML.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt btw you need 2 bytes per character for the StringBuilder to create the String and up to 2 bytes per character for the String itself.

Answer (score -2):

First of all, it is probably not recommended to use that much memory, and I would break it up into reasonably-sized chunks (maybe join 100 strings at a time and then write to a file). If you really must use that much memory, then you will need to pass `-Xmx10G` to the JVM. This allocates more heap space for Java to use.